# Full heigth containers filling remaining heigth

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am fighting on learning bootstrap 4 on redesigning a simple app.

The App has got a fixed height header, a fixed height footer and needs a flexible centered container using the remaining height.

It drives me crazy, cause I tried so many examples. None where working.

See this codepen of my last try.

```css
document, html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#topContainer{
  height: 95px;
}

#centerContainer{
  position: inherit;
  height: 100%;
}

#bottomContainer{
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->

  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Test Construction</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-flex bg-success h-100">

    <div id="topContainer" class="row flex-row bg-primary">
        <div class="col-4 bg-danger">1</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-info">2</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-dark">3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="centerContainer" class="row flex-row bg-secondary">
        <div class="col-4 bg-dark">1</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-danger">2</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-info">3</div>
    </div>

    <div id="bottomContainer" class="row flex-row bg-warning">
        <div class="col-4 bg-info">1</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-dark">2</div>
        <div class="col-4 bg-danger">3</div>
    </div>

</div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Any hint for me how I can handle this?

After a while I found an example which might be working. I tried it on my windows machine and cool it works
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aryXba

But the same layout in my symfony/bootstrap project on a linux machine in chrome does not work anymore

Comment: what do you mean that it doesn't work anymore (linux/chrome)? can you reproduce the issue via code here? or share a screenshot of what it means?

Answer (score 1):

here is a pretty simple example using bootstrap.

`flex-grow` applied to your center element will take up the remaining space dependent on the height of the container and the header and footer. Also note that for `flex-grow` to work your parent element needs to use flex box.

view example here
[Code Pen](https://codepen.io/boldstar/pen/JqZxKj)

Comment: If you add more content to the center div, it decreases the header and footer height

Answer (score 0):

flex-grow only works if the parent element has display flex  property

```css
  

*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
            
.top-fixed {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    }

.bottom-fixed {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.expandable {
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="top-fixed"></div>
    <div class="expandable"></div>
    <div class="bottom-fixed"></div>
</div>
```

In the above code snippet for parent element display flex propety is assigned , fixed header(top-fixed) and footer(bottom-fixed) are created and the center division is an expandable one it will occupy the remaining height

you can also change the flex direction based on your requirements